# How does recursive stack allocation with std::map work?

Tags: c++, memory, stdmap

How do stack allocated containers with internal references to themselves know when to allocate their children?

For example:

```
class Trie {
    public:
    struct Node {
        map<char, Node> letters;
        bool end;
    };

    Node root;

    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    Trie() {

    }

    /** Inserts a word into the trie. */
    void insert(string word) {
        Node *iter = &root;
        for(auto c: word) {
            iter = &iter->letters[c];
        }
        iter->end = true;
    }

    /** Returns if the word is in the trie. */
    bool search(string word) {
        Node *iter = &root;
        for(auto c: word) {
            if(iter->letters.find(c) == iter->letters.end()) return false;
            iter = &iter->letters[c];
        }
        return iter->end;
    }

    /** Returns if there is any word in the trie that starts with the given prefix. */
    bool startsWith(string prefix) {
        Node *iter = &root;
        for(auto c: prefix) {
            if(iter->letters.find(c) == iter->letters.end()) return false;
            iter = &iter->letters[c];
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

This code works but I'm not entirely sure why. (This is my solution to the Trie problem on LeetCode.)

I have a simple stack allocated root `Node` that contains a mapping of `char` -> `Node`. My question is when are the children nodes actually allocated? Does it happen once there is a reference to a Node under `letters`? (`iter = &iter->letters[c];`) Is this code just wildly incorrect and makes too many assumptions about undefined behavior?

Comment: The trick is in `letters[c]`. Read about what  `std::map::operator[](const Key&)` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map::operator[]` allows you the semantics of `map[key] = value` without the key being in the container already. Imagine if you did this with a `std::vector` of size `n`: if you call `v[v.size()]`, that reference is to unowned memory, to say the least. If you want it to be owned, you would have to resize the container first to make sure that the key (an index) is in range of the container.

So when you call `operator[]`, the container will check for the presence of your key and default construct a value for it if it doesn't exist, then return a reference to it as if it had been there the whole time. This is why `operator[]` is a mutating function; if the key is not present, the container's state will have mutated after the allocation and default construction of the new value.